# Asynchronously receive Datagram/TCP packet over Android Client Socket

Tags: android, sockets, tcp, udp

[image: Description of what is working]
As shown above, I have a socket server (in UDP) running on my Raspberry Pi. I also have a socket client running on my Android app.
Currently, the app client always initiates communication and the RasPi always responds.

The RasPi can even initiate communication and send socket packet to anyone if it knows the IP address.
The problem is my app has to wait for a Thread to receive data forever (basically polling). Like below:

```
uniSocket.receive(receivePacket);
```

Should both RasPi and Android run clients and servers or is there something like Datagram_Socket_Callback or some asynchronous method to receive and send data.

Comment: An UDP server can broadcast data. Isn't that usable?

Comment: And after a year I have this problem too, you couldn`t find any useful solution?

Answer (score 0):

The receive call will block until there is something to receive. That isn't polling; it's just waiting. It could wait in the receive call for days at a time if there's no notification to be sent. And that occupies no more resources than a server threading running on the android side (waiting for a connection) would occupy.

You probably will need some kind of periodic keep-alive to ensure the other side hasn't disappeared. You can do that yourself at the application layer, or TCP provides a keep-alive mechanism you can activate with `setsockopt` for this purpose.

In other words, create a socket, enable TCP keep-alives, send an "I'm waiting for notifications" message to the server, and then call receive to wait. The server then maintains a list of client connections waiting for notifications, and can then send data through a connection whenever there is something to be sent.

For your normal client-server communications, you could use the same socket, but it might be more complicated to synchronize that way, so alternatively, you could just create another socket in parallel.

I don't know a lot about android/app development but obviously your client will need to be prepared to re-create the connection if it's broken. I can think of many reasons why that might happen in normal usage. For example, the initial connection might be created from an IP address obtained on your home network. Then you walk out of your house and lose that IP address. You may now need to recreate the connection with a different IP address on the cell network (or the wifi at the coffee shop or whatever). If the phone goes into Airplane mode, you might lose all IP addresses for a time.

I'm sure it's possible to create a server that runs in android as well, but then you have the problem of the RPi needing to know the android's IP address which may change frequently. I would say it's better to keep the client role on the android side.